# That speaks volumes to me

Tags: idioms

What does

> That [speaks volumes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/speak_volumes) **to me**

mean? Could you elaborate it in terms of feelings please?

For example in a context:

> This quote speaks volumes to me

My guesses are the following but I am not sure how close I am.

It makes a sense for me. I think in the same way.

It is already true for me ( and my life).

It is wise and I will apply it to my life.

Answer (score 2):

**A situation as given in words or descriptions is said to speak volumes for or to somebody.**

"The plight of the poor in urban slums speaks volumes to me."
"The fact he doesn't help his family speaks volumes to me."

Not a **quote**. Some situation **speaks volumes** to me.

It means: is meaningful to me in an important manner.

Comment: Thank you. I know what you try to explain to me here. However, people can use this   phrase for  situations such as " verbal suggestions or advice". My questions is especially for these situations.

Comment: "This quote speaks volumes to me" means: what is contained in the quote is meaningful for me. Usually, that would refer to some kind of truth about life.